# Why does (x – y <= j – k – 1) evaluate to FALSE?

Tags: java, evaluate

What is happening here?

Below is the

```
int i = 1, j = 2, k = 3;  
double x = 5.5, y = 7.7;

x - y <= j - k - 1 FALSE

-i + 5 * j >= k + 1 TRUE
```

Comment: Both are true. Are you sure you are getting a false on the first one ?

Comment: Floating point numbers on a binary system often result in non-exact numeric representations.

Comment: Did you try to debug it?

Comment: @ryyker Not here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It (obviously) doesn’t:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        int i = 1, j = 2, k = 3;  
        double x = 5.5, y = 7.7;
 
        System.err.printf("%f <= %d: %s\n", x - y, j - k - 1, x - y <= j - k - 1);
    }
}
```

yields:

```
-2.200000 <= -2: true
```

But note that the code you’ve posted contains invalid Unicode characters that would lead to a compilation error.